# Program fails with strange errors in Wine

Tags: 13.04, wine

I just installed [Silhouette Studio](http://www.silhouetteamerica.com/?page=software) in Wine.  The installation appeared to finish, but when running the program it hangs infinitely at "initializing."  When launched from a terminal, I get the following output:

```
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_GetContentLength (0x60745520)->(0x8f60e0)
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x607c60b0)->(0x8f5e28)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x5f9d7dd8)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x5f9f99b8)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x603c6d78)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x6065d338)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x5d9a6980)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x12465878)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x607c06d8)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60659e78)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_GetContentLength (0x606feb10)->(0x8f6500)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x607e7560)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x5da49050)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x6074fae0)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x5eeed968)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_GetContentLength (0x603d8998)->(0x8f6500)
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60169800)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x605e0918)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x5f9ff4a8)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x5d9a3b18)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x132245e0)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x6038fe90)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x152dd960)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x605ccb70)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x5ec277d8)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x606e8518)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x607edb30)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x607e26a8)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x14bc74d0)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60745280)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x606d7fd8)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x607e0c60)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60635898)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x607e1898)->(0x8f5e28)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x5da493b0)->(0x8f5e28)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x605ad778)->(0x8f5e28)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x6068ad38)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x607ec350)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x14ab5890)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x5fbedca8)->(0x8f6248)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 28
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b6c9b0)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b6cf78)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b6d540)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b6f110)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b6f6d8)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b6fca0)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b70240)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b70300)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b71148)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b710d0)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x607be970)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b72590)->()
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 69 of CGID_Explorer
fixme:ieframe:PropertyNotifySink_OnChanged unimplemented dispid 1005
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 69 of CGID_Explorer
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60218fa0)->(0x8f5df4 0x8f5964 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b6cec0)->(0x8f5df4 0x8f5964 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b6d488)->(0x8f5df4 0x8f5964 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b6f058)->(0x8f5df4 0x8f5964 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b6f620)->(0x8f5df4 0x8f5964 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b6fbe8)->(0x8f5df4 0x8f5964 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b701b8)->(0x8f5df4 0x8f5964 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b708b0)->(0x8f5df4 0x8f5964 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b70fe8)->(0x8f5df4 0x8f5964 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b71628)->(0x8f5df4 0x8f5964 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x607be8d8)->(0x8f5df4 0x8f5964 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b724d8)->(0x8f5df4 0x8f5964 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b72ab8)->(0x8f5df4 0x8f5964 0)
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x602e0a50)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60a68f70)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b735e8)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b335f8)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b416a8)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b709c8)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b42580)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b42b80)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b72130)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b43ec8)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b43e38)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b44a90)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b44a00)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60240850)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x602407c0)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b48350)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b48900)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b48f18)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b49530)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b49b48)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b4a160)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b4a778)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b4ad90)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b4b3a8)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b533b8)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b55c38)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60220dd8)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60221290)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60221880)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60222488)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x603fa9b8)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x603fafb8)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b43188)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b43c68)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b438f0)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x603fb810)->()
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60b475d0)->()
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60a68d78)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60a68fd0)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60a69858)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60240700)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b41d08)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b42188)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b42a88)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b71b68)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b43dd0)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b443d0)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b445a8)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b44f98)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b45170)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b47938)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b47e50)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b48500)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b48e20)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b49438)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b49a50)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b4a068)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b4a680)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b4ac98)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b4b2b0)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b4b8c8)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b55b40)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b55df8)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60221198)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60221788)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60221d88)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b41f10)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x603faec0)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b43090)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b43690)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60b43888)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x603782d0)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x603788c8)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x603fc388)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_GetContentLength (0x606ff170)->(0x8f5830)
fixme:mshtml:nsURI_GetOriginCharset (0x604b58b8)->(0x8f3644)
fixme:mshtml:nsHttpChannelInternal_SetDocumentURI (0x60479580)->()
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b6c9b0)->(0x8f5158)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b6f110)->(0x8f5158)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b6d540)->(0x8f5158)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:mshtml:HttpNegotiate_GetRootSecurityId (0x60439c30)->(0x8f6214 0x8f5d84 0)
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b6f6d8)->(0x8f5578)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x607be970)->(0x8f5578)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b71148)->(0x8f5578)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b6cf78)->(0x8f5578)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b6fca0)->(0x8f5578)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b710d0)->(0x8f5578)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x602e0a50)->(0x8f5578)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b72590)->(0x8f5578)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b70240)->(0x8f5578)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b70300)->(0x8f5578)
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b335f8)->(0x8f5578)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b735e8)->(0x8f5578)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b42b80)->(0x8f5578)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60a68f70)->(0x8f5578)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b416a8)->(0x8f5158)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b48900)->(0x8f5158)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b43ec8)->(0x8f5158)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60b475d0)->(0x8f5578)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60479580)->(0x8f5668)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 28
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x607cc608)->(0x8f37b8)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x6083a720)->(0x8f3bd8)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x606ac6e0)->(0x8f3bd8)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x6051c070)->(0x8f3bd8)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60408e90)->(0x8f3bd8)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x607d0e90)->(0x8f3bd8)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x606b0640)->(0x8f3bd8)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
fixme:wininet:InternetLockRequestFile STUB
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_IsNoCacheResponse (0x60878420)->(0x8f3bd8)
fixme:wininet:URLCache_FindFirstFreeEntry Grow file
err:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal no free entries
Killed
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Are there extra Wine packages that can be installed?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I was able to get it to work through the following method.  I still don't know how to "fix" the problems, but this seems to help avoid them.

1) If a version of the program is installed in Wine, remove it using the "Wine uninstall programs."

2) Add the [Ubuntu Wine Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa) to your sources:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`

3) Upgrade to the latest Wine (currently 1.5) with `dist-upgrade`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

4) Verify that any old version of the program is uninstalled in Wine using the "Wine uninstall programs."

5) Reinstall the program using the "Wine uninstall programs."  There is an option to "Add" a program.  Use this to select the .exe and install.

6) Repeat steps 4 and 5 until it works.  For me it worked the second time.